# Jquery - can't parse data correctly

Tags: jquery

I send data from php script to my Jquery function.
data are as:

`[[{"t":"Knjige, revije, stripi"},{"t":"Vse ostalo"},...']]`

Jquery code:

```
function newFunction(data){
jQuery.each(data, function(index, tag) {  
    $('#list').append('<li>' + tag + '</li>');
    });
}
```

the problem is I get list as:

```
[
[
"
A
v
d
i
o
"
,
"
O
s
t
a
l
i
"
,
```

everything in own line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data variable is still a string, so each() is going through each character. You have to parse it first.

```
function newFunction(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    jQuery.each(data, function(index, tag) {  
        $('#list').append('<li>' + tag + '</li>');
    });
}
```